# Limit of the following function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

For a function $g(t)$ with $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow\infty}g(t)=G$, what is the limit $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow\infty}e^{-t}\int g(t)e^{3t}dt$?

Edit: I've thought about using user26977's tip about L'Hopital and got $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow\infty}e^{-t}\int g(t)e^{3t}dt=\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow\infty}e^{-t}g(t)e^{3t}=\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow\infty}e^{2t}g(t).$
Is this $\infty$? Is my reasoning here correct?

Comment: @user42912 Not much, what could I have tried?

Comment: My first thought is that it should be zero, because of the $e^{-t}$, but then why give the G?

Comment: L'Hopital rule I guess

Comment: @user26977 And how would that look in this case? (i know what it is, just not how I could use it here)

Comment: What are the limits on your integrals?

Comment: @vonbrand No limits

Answer (score 1):

We can apply l'Hôpital also in the generic form “whatever/$\infty$”: so your limit is
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\displaystyle\int g(t)e^{3t}\,dt}{e^t}
=
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{g(t)e^{3t}}{e^t}
$$
Now the information you have is not conclusive; if $G>0$, then you can say the limit is $\infty$ and, similarly, the limit is $-\infty$ for $G<0$.

However, there is no answer if $G=0$; for instance, if $g(t)=e^{-t}$, the limit is $\infty$; if $g(t)=e^{-2t}$, the limit is $1$; if $g(t)=e^{-3t}$, the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that $\lim_{t \to infty} g(t) = G$ doesn't help. Take e.g. $g(t) = G$, then the integral is just $\frac{1}{3} G e^{3 t} + c$, and there is no limit. If you take e.g. $g(t) = 0$ if $t < t_0$, $g(t) = G$ if $t \ge t_0$, there is a limit if $t < t_0$, and none (as above, essentially) if $t \ge t_0$.